# Android Compose how to ignore user interaction inside SwipeToDismiss?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a UI with Jetpack Compose where each list item can be swiped, once one list item is swiped I trigger a network request, so I show a progress in the swiped item and I would like to disable user interaction while the request runs, how to achieve this in compose?

```
LazyColumn(        
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    ) {
        items(
            items = filteredItems,
        ) { listItem->
           SwipeToDismiss(
...
```

Comment: You can set positionalThreshold to 0.dp.toPx( ) when you are processing the network request.